# Where can I find CSS Outline in visual studio express 2013 for web

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to find the CSS Outline tab in visual studio express 2013 for web, it's supposed to pop up automatically when you open up a css.style sheet but I don't see it!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to View, Other Windows, Document Outline. Or Ctrl + Alt + T.

reference:
http://forums.asp.net/t/873897.aspx?CSS+Outline+Window+Where+did+it+go+